# Any non-exorcism style of healing miracles recorded in the Scripture?

Tags: life-of-jesus, miracles, exorcism

> And Jesus rebuked the devil; and he departed out of him: and the child was cured from that very hour.

Is there any non-exorcism style of healing miracles(nothing like resurrection of Lazarus but specifically of healing a sick person) written in the Bible?

**The question was thrown before due research. please disregard it. I am leaving it as it is because the answer below is a good example**

Comment: I have voted to close as this is very broad. Even a quick glance at the Gospels (Matthew, Mark, Luke & John) will reveal many examples of healing types of miracles that do not reference demonic activity. Since you have found one *with* demonic activity, I assume you will be able to find plenty without.

Comment: @Flimzy Yes, it deserves downvote. Wine miracle isn't "healing miracle" by the way. I saw a few healing miracles that involved either in devil thing or in lack of faith. Below one is very good one and actually I came across that before but memory always betrays me.

Comment: @Flimzy again, I admit due research wasn't done before asking. Thanks.

Comment: @Wikis It is not very broad. In fact, it is extremely narrow with a simple yes/no answer, and the answer is "yes." As for the lack of research, and the fact that you could find the answer easily elsewhere, yes that is true; however, I do believe it is common Stack Exchange behavior to allow even simple questions which someone could get from the first result of a Google query, even without clicking on the result. I disagree with that behavior, but last I knew that was "the Stack Exchange way." I got scolded before for leaving a comment telling someone "Just google it, it's the first result"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loads! Eg [John 9:1-12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+9%3A1-12&version=NIVUK):

> As he [Jesus] went along, he saw a man blind from birth. His disciples asked him, ‘Rabbi, who sinned, this man or his parents, that he was born blind?’
>
> ‘Neither this man nor his parents sinned,’ said Jesus, ‘but this happened so that the works of God might be displayed in him. As long as it is day, we must do the works of him who sent me. Night is coming, when no one can work. While I am in the world, I am the light of the world.’
>
> After saying this, he spat on the ground, made some mud with the saliva, and put it on the man’s eyes.  ‘Go,’ he told him, ‘wash in the Pool of Siloam’ (this word means ‘Sent’). So the man went and washed, and came home seeing.
>
> His neighbours and those who had formerly seen him begging asked, ‘Isn’t this the same man who used to sit and beg?’ Some claimed that he was.
>
> Others said, ‘No, he only looks like him.’
>
> But he himself insisted, ‘I am the man.’
>
> ‘How then were your eyes opened?’ they asked.
>
> He replied, ‘The man they call Jesus made some mud and put it on my eyes. He told me to go to Siloam and wash. So I went and washed, and then I could see.’
>
> ‘Where is this man?’ they asked him. ‘I don’t know,’ he said.

Comment: Good. Thanks! Mind if I delete the question?

Comment: @msk - sure. If there is a reason why you asked this that I'm missing, please let me know - here or in [chat].